# A Script to insert dummy Data in all tables of DB

Tags: sql-server

There is an SP posted in the below link stating that it will insert dummy data in the entire DB. But the SP works only for a single table. Can anyone please share the one where we can insert dummy data throughout the db?

[A Script to insert dummy Data in all tables of Database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19938/a-script-to-insert-dummy-data-in-all-tables-of-database)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for a staging environment to test performance before release. What i ended up doing was using sql data generator by redgate.

Way easier than a custom solution.

[sql red gate sql data generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/)